# is there a way to put delete button on the left side

Tags: django, django-admin, django-3.1

[image]

Is there a way to put the delete button on the left side? i try to use `ordering` but it doesnt work because delete is not part of the `model`

here is my `admin.py`

```
class CategoryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Category
    extra = 0


class SurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "is_published")
    inlines = [CategoryInline, QuestionInline]
```

Comment: Show your model admin code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Delete?" section is hard-coded to be after the fields in this [admin template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html#L20).

You'll have override this admin template in order to change it. [This section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) in the docs explain how to override an admin template.

Essentially, you'll need to copy [this template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html#L20) and save it under `<YOUR-APP-DIR>/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html`. And then you can edit it to move the "Delete?" column to the front.